# How to fillna dynamically using reduce in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, reduce

I have created this function to apply fillna based on input params to a dataframe but it seems like it overwrites the last param e.g. missing here and instead of on the output of first param.

Here is my function:

```
def fillna(df, params):
    return reduce(
        lambda data, rules: data.fillna(rules[0], subset=rules[1]), params.items(), df,
    )


where df: input dataframe
params={0:['age'], Missing: ['name']} # 

input : 
id age name
1  12   tan
2       saks
3  23
 
output:
   id age name
   1  12   tan
   2  0    saks
   3  23   missing
```

Comment: what is your expected output? The code seems to be working.

Comment: Can you tell us what's not working as expected? A comparison between the output you obtain and the one you expect would probably help for instance.